# Azure devops - git repo synchronization

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell

I created a pipeline in azure devops, added three tasks in order listed below:
1) Command line task
2) Powershell task
3) Command line task

task 1)

```
git config --global user.email "xxx@xx.com"
git config --global user.name "xxxx"
cd $(Build.SourcesDirectory)
git init
```

task 2) Powershell task

task 3)

```
git add filename.csv
git commit -m "csv file update"
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin  https://OrgName@dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_git/RepoName
git push -u origin HEAD:master
```

I used this solution in a different subscription and there was no problem. I moved solution to second subscription and I am still facing issue: `fatal: could not read Password for https://OrgName@dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_git/RepoName: terminal prompts disabled[error]Cmd.exe exited with code 128`

I have configured the repo using this [MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/scripts/git-commands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)
Something is wrong with **task 3)**. **tasks 1)** and **task 2)** completed successfully.

Comment: `I moved solution to second subscription` are you saying you put these pipeline tasks in a pipeline under a different organization?

Comment: Hi, Yes, put these pipeline tasks in a pipeline under a different organization, in previous organization there was no problem, after migration I am facing mentioned issues.

Comment: In the next organization, did you want it push the file to another organization? Does the org you want this git push to same with the current pipeline located?

Comment: Hi @Merlin Liang, I want to push file into repo located in the same organization. the same pipeline.

Comment: @tester81, That's odd to prompt this error message. Does below format could help for solve the error? Since the error said could not read password, I think attack the token in the command may meet the password requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with below push script, which [attached](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page#use-your-personal-access-token) the PAT token in the git command to authorized the operation:

```
git push https://{PAT}@dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_git/{repos name} master
```

Use this command and replace the original `git remote add origin` and `git push`.

**UPDATE:**

To make you more clear about how to apply it into the task, I reproduced it on my side.

*Note:* No changes are required to the original first `Command line task` and `Powershell task`, the below changes are only in the **second** `Command line task`:

```
git checkout $(Build.SourceBranchName)
git add .
git commit -m "aaaa"
git push https://{token}@dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_git/{repos} master
```

When we apply the token in the git command, the whole script need to be changed. Please replace above script all in the second `Command line task`.

Comment: I updated the git code: `git add filename.csv
git commit -m "csv file update"
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin  https://PAT@dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_git/RepoName
git push -u origin HEAD:master` and I got error like: The following project does not exist: ProjectName. Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Azure DevOps Server.
fatal: repository 'https://PAT@dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_git/RepoName' not found, I used this link and was able to open my repository.

Comment: @tester81, what's the result? Is any error prompt now?

Comment: As I mentioned, and I got error like: The following project does not exist: ProjectName. Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Azure DevOps Server. fatal: repository 'PAT@dev.azure.com/OrgName/ProjectName/_git/RepoName' not found, I used this link and was able to open my repository.

Comment: @tester81. I wrote a completed script to execute the git push command with token. Please have a try then let me know is it work for you.(It succeed on my side)

Comment: Still facing an error, message `remote: TFxxxx: The following project does not exist: ProjectName. Verify that the name of the project is correct and that the project exists on the specified Azure DevOps Server.` I think something is wrong with the project name, My project name contains two words and a space between them, like "Word1 Word2", and in this line `git push https://{token}@dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_git/{repos} master` I am using projectname like "Word1%20Word2", and I can open the link in my browser, but GIT cant handle this I suppose.

Comment: @tester81, you can got this path from the git clone button, and then made some modified on this url(input the PAT)

Comment: @ Merlin Liang - MSFT, I know that, I am using this link, link is ok, I can open it in my browser, but when I use this link in the following line `git push https://{token}@dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_git/{repos} master` something is wrong, like GIT is not able to read project name correctly, In pipeling error message I see error message mentioned above and info that there is my project doesnt exist.

Comment: @tester81. This relevant with command line task compile logic. When we run the command in a command prompt, we have to escape the percentage sign for the space as `%%20`. Please try with this format. I just tried on my side with the project and repos name has space, and it worked .

Comment: Hi @Merlin, I used this `%%20`, I got error, I am not able to open link using proposed combination. When I am using this `%20` i can open the link, but there is still an error when executing task via pipeline. I can ope this link `https://{token}@dev.azure.com/{org name}/{project name}/_git/{repos}` in my browser but using GIT commands in pipeline still facing the same error mentioned above.

Comment: @tester81. So odd. When I apply the %%20 in command line task, it is worked on my side. This %%20 only need to be applied in command line task, because it would compile the %20 as another character. So I suggest you add another % to avoid the convert. What's error message on your side?

Comment: @tester81, see my configuration and my log: https://imgur.com/a/jzAhAW5 you can see my project name and the repos name all has space.

Comment: Yes, it worked, additional "%", but as You mentioned, link with double "%" doesnt work in the browser, additional "%" should be only added in GIT command line task! Thank You very much!!!

Comment: @tester81, you're so welcome. Awesome that you could run successfully now:-0